# Visual Studio 2013 won't let me create code behind file for Web Site project

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm editing a VB.Net web site project in Visual Studio 2013. All the aspx files use inline code. I need to create a code behind file for one aspx page so I can access some control events. For some reason there is no option to add only a code behind file. I can create a new aspx page with built in code behind but I can't add a code behind file to an already existing page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following the directions here? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikhailarkhipov/archive/2006/04/13/576117.aspx

Comment: It won't let me create the code behind file at all. The site was developed very poorly so I will have to stick with inline code so I won't be able to access the events of the controls on the page. I'll have to come up with an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

The site being developed "very poorly" shouldn't have an impact on whether or not a an aspx file *can* have a code behind file.

I don't have vb templates installed, but here is what I went through to add a code behind file to a class that didn't have it.

Here i have new project and deleted the code behind file

[image: Shows aspx page without a code behind page]

Right click the solution, add class, type in "WebForm1.aspx.cs" (.vb in your case), hit enter

[image: add class dialogue]

Voila! code behind file.  Note that you'll probably need to add the "code behind" tag to the aspx page - see my first screenshot as an example.

```
CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"
```

[image: the newly added code behind file (note it is now nested with the aspx]

Forgot to mention you'll want to make the newly created code behind file inherit from "Page" as so:

[image: update the newly generated code behind file to extend page]

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it won't give me the add class option. I can only add a web form but not a class. I tried adding a new web form and then copying the code behind and renaming it but that did not work.